# SPARQL query to retrieve all DBPedia literary grenre

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I can retrieve a list of all Books `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Book>` in DBpedia just fine using the following query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
select distinct ?bookUri  
where { ?bookUri  rdf:type ontology:Book . }
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20ontology%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%20%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20?bookUri%20%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%20?bookUri%20%20rdf%3atype%20ontology%3aBook%20.%20%7D%20&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

But I can't retrieve literaryGenre `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/literaryGenre>` with almost the exact same query.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
select distinct ?genreUri  
where { ?genreUri  rdf:type ontology:literaryGenre . }
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20ontology%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%20%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20?genreUri%20%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%20?genreUri%20%20rdf%3atype%20ontology%3aliteraryGenre%20.%20%7D%20&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I am utterly confused.  These queries can be run on the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

Comment: It looks like your first and second queries are the same.  The first one should say `?bookUri rdf:type ontology:Book`, no?

Comment: Yes!  My copy-paste mistake.  Fixing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/literaryGenre` is not a `owl:Class`, but rather an object property.  Indeed, on the page you linked to, http://dbpedia.org/ontology/literaryGenre, we read:

> About: literary genre
>
> An Entity of Type : ObjectProperty, from Named
>   Graph : http://dbpedia.org/resource/classes#, within Data Space :
>   dbpedia.org
>
> A literary genre is a category of literary composition.
>   Genres may be determined by literary technique, tone, content, or even
>   (as in the case of fiction) length.

As a result, you can look at the literary genre of books from [the public endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) with a query like this:

```
select distinct * where {
  ?book dbpedia-owl:literaryGenre ?genre .
}
limit 100
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%2a%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?book%20dbpedia-owl%3aliteraryGenre%20?genre%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

What's useful there, though, is that you can examine the resources that are the objects of the literary genre properties, e.g., http://dbpedia.org/resource/Adventure_Novel, and in doing this you can find some properties that might help you find more.  For instance, Adventure_Novel has properties:

```
rdf:type        yago:LiteraryGenres
dcterms:subject category:Literary_genres
dcterms:subject category:Adventure_fiction
```

What you might also notice in browsing that page, however, is that Advenure_Novel is the object of not only `dbpedia-owl:literaryGenre` statements, but also `dbpedia-owl:genre` and `dbpedia-owl:format`.  (I've ignored the older `dbpprop` properties.)  So you've got two options:

1. You can query for things that have `rdf:type yago:LiteraryGenres`, or have `dcterms:subject category:Literary_genres`, with a query like this which produces 243 results:

   ```
   select distinct ?genre where {
     { ?genre rdf:type yago:LiteraryGenres }
     UNION 
     { ?genre dcterms:subject category:Literary_genres }
   }
   ```

   [SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?genre%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?genre%20rdf%3atype%20yago%3aLiteraryGenres%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?genre%20dcterms%3asubject%20category%3aLiterary_genres%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)
2. You can ask for things that the object of `dbpedia-owl:genre` and `dbpedia-owl:format` (there are 8434):

   ```
   select distinct ?genre where {
     { [] dbpedia-owl:format ?genre } 
     UNION 
     { [] dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre }
     UNION
     { [] dbpedia-owl:literaryGenre ?genre }
   }
   ```

   [SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?genre%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%5B%5D%20dbpedia-owl%3aformat%20?genre%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20UNION%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%5B%5D%20dbpedia-owl%3agenre%20?genre%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%5B%5D%20dbpedia-owl%3aliteraryGenre%20?genre%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

   However, you'll note that in that query, there are some results from `format` that are more like a publication medium, e.g., `Docudrama` and `Music_download`.  As such, it probably makes more sense to stick to those that are explicitly genres (7940 results):

   ```
   select distinct ?genre where {
     { [] dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre }
     UNION 
     { [] dbpedia-owl:literaryGenre ?genre }
   }
   ```

   [SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?genre%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%5B%5D%20dbpedia-owl%3agenre%20?genre%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%5B%5D%20dbpedia-owl%3aliteraryGenre%20?genre%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

   Looking at these results, though, many of the genres are not literary genres but, e.g., genres of music, which means you're probably even better just looking at the `literaryGenre` property (936 results):

   ```
   select distinct ?genre where {
     [] dbpedia-owl:literaryGenre ?genre
   }
   ```

   [SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?genre%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5B%5D%20dbpedia-owl%3aliteraryGenre%20?genre%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Based on these results, it looks like the *best* option is to select things that are object of `dbpedia-owl:literaryGenre` statements.